# Problem with Parse Server vs Oracle Cloud

Tags: node.js, parse-server, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, parse-dashboard

I've spent the last 3 days trying to make a Ubuntu Oracle Cloud VPS a parse server (Yes, I know services like Google Firebase and Back4App but my website consume a lot of requests by a user/hour and I don't have money to spend right now), so I followed this tutorial:

https://dev.to/autodidaktum/how-to-deploy-parse-server-and-parse-dashboard-on-digital-ocean-2021-3o5h

I have followed every step just changing little things like node version (I got the most updated) and didn't create a network domain.

Everything ran "ok" (I had to install some packages and force the parse-server download) but when I reached the "Install Parse Server", the last part of it says to run `npm index.js` but npm returns with something like: "execute `npm run lint`", sounded really ok to me but when I ran it, returned me the message:

> parse-server-example@1.4.0 lint
> eslint --cache ./cloud && eslint --cache index.js && eslint --cache ./spec

and no reach from my browser from "{ip floating address}:1337" (yes, I know that {ip floating address} means the external IP), so I thought I was missing to open a port for access in both areas like inside the server and the Virtual Cloud Network, I opened them (images below) and still no reach.

[image: Oracle VCN]
[image: Ubuntu iptables list]

I let it go and went to the "Install Parse Dashboard" step and started the server, nice message

> The dashboard is now available at http://0.0.0.0:4040/

another browser test and still no reach. (obviously, I have tested with externalIp:4040)

*The real question is, I did something wrong based on this information?*

Comment: Let's first talk about the dashboard. When you say, I started the server, what command did you use?

Comment: `parse-dashboard --config /opt/parse-dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json` just as the tutorial, @DaviMacêdo

Comment: I believe you can even use this command to test the connection but you need to make sure you don't stop the command nor close the ssh session. Section `Run Parse Server and Parse Dashboard by Default` looks to show a more reliable way to run it. Anyways, while running the command, you should be able to open the dashboard. When you open the address, what error do you receive on your browser?

Comment: You're right, I didn't stop the command neither the ssh session, just changed the window (I know I shouldn't but I use Windows), the browser error was `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. That's why I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Connection timeout uses to be due to firewall issues or something else blocking access to the server. Maybe you should ask help for oracle cloud.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo , in the last 20 days I was fighting with Oracle to find the problem, and then they proved to me my instance was the problem. Then I verified with LSOF command and they were right.

They sent a 20-line report showing how VCN was ok. Then I terminated the old instance and create a new one. Went to UFW and add 4040 and 1337, still no results, unreachable and unlisted in LSOF.

I really don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Why don't to try the same steps on a different provider? So we can double check if the problem is Oracle related or not.

Comment: The problem, after all, is money, I didn't find any free Linux server or at least a good trial (I have spent the AWS year in another project and I don't trust google billing methods) and I want a place to stay without big figures problem.

I'd love to stay with Back4App, but I have made a calculation and would explode the transaction free-limit within days if the website goes right. (Also, I have answered your friend Alysson's e-mail and got no feedback)

Comment: I am not sure why you believe that the web-site will hit the limits in few days but another alternative could be hosting the database on Back4App and the web-site elsewhere. Anyways, I am not trying to sell Back4App to you. In the case you decide to go with self-hosting, I suggest you to try a different provider, so you can be sure if it's a problem related to Oracle specific setup or it is something related to what you are doing in the instance.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, I've doubted myself about how it would reach, and then I made a worksheet to prove myself (it reached 43350 requests in 24h in the best case). I can send it to you and/or forward the e-mail I have sent to Alysson who explains a little bit about the project if you want so.

Comment: Sure. Please open a ticket on the web-site with your thoughts.